# I have the error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a mysql database. I would like to connect to it with the script i wrote :

```
<?php

function getDatabase() {
    $host = 'localhost:3306';
    $db = 'freya';
    $login = 'root';
    $pw = 'helloitsme';

    try {
        return new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8', $login, $pw);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}

$db = getDatabase();
```

I have seen that this error is recurent but none of the solutions worked for.
I checked the my.cnf, and i'm sure that i'm using the port where the mysql db is.
I'm also sure that the db name, the login and the password are correct, because i'm using them to reach the db with the shell.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to specify the port as 3306 is default for mysql, but if you do, the correct connection string is

```
'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306 ...'
```